# Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a database via:

```
create database test_db;
```

Then I created a user via:

```
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'test_db' IDENTIFIED BY 'test_pass';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'test'@'test';
```

now when i try to connect to it via PHP, i used the following code:

```
    $hostname_localhost ="localhost";  
    $database_localhost ="test_db";  
    $username_localhost ="test_user";  
    $password_localhost ="test_pass";  
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_localhost;dbname=$database_localhost",$username_localhost,$password_localhost);
        echo 'Connected to DB'.'<br />';
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user,host from mysql.user");
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo $row['user'].'@'.$row['host'].'<br />';
        }

        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getTraceAsString().$e->getLine().$e->getMessage();
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'test_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

please tell me how to fix this. how do i connect to my test user via PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your create user / grant should be:

```
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test_pass';
grant all privileges on test_db.* to 'test_user'@'localhost';
```

I also noticed your SQL Select statement is from `mysql.user`. If you want `test_user` to have access to query from that database, you would need another `GRANT` statement and or change the `test_db` part in the grant statement to `*.` I am not sure what your use case is and or what you need, but just a heads up.

The syntax for the Create User goes as follows:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'host_or_IPAddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

For the grant it is (omitted a few items, please read the referenced material for more in depth options / information):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'samehostascreateuser';
```

For your reference / reading: [MySQL Create User](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) and [Mysql Grant Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/grant.html)

Comment: in case i dont want to use the database(after @) then..??

i am sorry i am a bit new to MySQL. so wanted to know.

Comment: @ Vineet Verma  I added a bit more to help you see how the syntax works.